# CvVideoCamera as VideoCapture replacement

Tags: ios, opencv

I currently have working C++ code that utilizes my laptop camera and OpenCV to detect obstacles. Now I want to adjust this code, so it can use the back camera of an iPad. From the iOS video processing tutorials on the OpenCV site I gathered that I need to use `CvVideoCamera`, as it is a wrapper around the iOS camera SDK. The issue I have is that the Method 
`- (void) processImage: (cv::Mat &) image`
seems to be the only way of interacting with it. Currently I am using a `VideoCapture` instance, from which I gather frames via `cap >> frame`. Is there some way to get similar functionality via `CvVideoCamera`? In order to perform obstacle detection I need to perform processing on sets of subsequent frames, not just a single frame. Hence I would like some capture object which I can query for the next frame within my obstacle detection method.